# How to store returned value of an Anonymous function to a Variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am extremely new to JavaScript so please bear with me on this one. 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
function Course(title, instructor, views){

  this.title= title;
  this.instructor = instructor;
  this.views = views;
  this.updateViews = function() {
    return ++this.views;
  };

}

var course1 =   new Course('JS', 'Sarun', 0);

console.log(course1.updateViews);
```

On execution however, I had expected the value of course1.updateViews to be 1. Instead, I get the entire function displayed in the console as follows:

```
ƒ () {
    return ++this.views;
  }
```

I am sure that this is a beginner's mistake. So can anyone please Correct me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So can anyone please Correct me on this?

You need to **invoke the function** using `()`

```
console.log(course1.updateViews());
```

```js
function Course(title, instructor, views){

  this.title= title;
  this.instructor = instructor;
  this.views = views;
  this.updateViews = function() {
    return ++this.views;
  };

}

var course1 =   new Course('JS', 'Sarun', 0);

console.log(course1.updateViews());
```

Comment: yup this helps!! thanks a lot!! Silly mistake from my side

Answer (score 0):

Because in the Course object,  you declared `this.updateViews` as function. 
if you wanna get return value of function, you need to invoke that by calling:

```
console.log(course1.updateViews());
```

if you wanna `updateViews` is static attribute you can change the way to declare this:

```
function Course(title, instructor, views){

  this.title= title;
  this.instructor = instructor;
  this.views = views;
  this.updateViews = ++this.views;

}
```